# Java format currency and concatenate with string

Tags: jasper-reports

I recently upgraded my jasperserver from version 4 to version 6.3 and changed from I report to Jasper studio.  I used to format my titles like the following

```
"Total " + new java.text.DecimalFormat("£ #,##0.00").format($V{field1_1})
```

Doing this results in the following error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

How should I perform this operation now?

Comment: Which part of this line throws the exception?

Comment: @jasemilly What is a type of `$V{field1_1}`?

Comment: unsure it just says error and throws that, the expression editor shows no issues.

Comment: it's a double.  has been for several years.

Comment: Looks like the reason of error is another expression, not this one

Comment: You should post small *jrxml* to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 0):

Please check what value you are getting in $V{field1_1}. There is no problem with this statement

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Total " + new java.text.DecimalFormat("£ #,##0.00").format(1000.11));
}
```

Comment: It's a variable field that just totals up numbers, no strange value and it isn't null.

Comment: @AlexK How does it makes a difference even if it's not a simple java app?

Comment: @jasemilly It must not be the problem with this statement then. Please check the stactrace and identify the line number.

Comment: I don't think that line is the error just created an empty report added a text field and pasted the line in with a value to format and it worked.